# How to retrieve a Blob as a string from SQLite?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I've checked other SO answers, but none seems to work in my particular case.

I'm retrieved the value as follows:

```
byte[] bytBLOB = new byte[reader.GetBytes(1, 0, null, 0, int.MaxValue) - 1];
reader.GetBytes(1, 0, bytBLOB, 0, bytBLOB.Length);

var value = Encoding.Default.GetString(bytBLOB);
```

However the value is: `e\0n\0_\0U\0S` when it should be just `en_us`.

How can I convert it properly?

Comment: can you cast the  blob to string in the sql?

Comment: @BugFinder That's what I was doing originally but it produced the same results as above.

Comment: maybe the problem then lies with how it got in there?

Comment: Just curious: Why do you save a string as blob in the first place?

Comment: @BugFinder It's not something that I can control. It's a Db with just one table storing KeyValue pairs.

Comment: Why are you using the `Default` encoding? Do you know the encoding of the blob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the blob is encoded in UTF-16.
Then something like this could happen.

Try:

```
var value = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-16").GetString(bytBLOB);
```